# Recursive Algorithm Issue

Tags: java, recursion

I have a network of streets, each street can diverge into two streets, so similarly two streets can converge into one street. 
Every time a convergence or divergence happens, there exists a node. And then there are work zone spans that get placed on top of streets 
(so a workzone span can hover over multiple streets). Now the idea is that I have to basically scan and find where the workzones begin, 
and place (at least) 5 warning signs in the traversable path leading to where the workzone actually begins. each warning sign has to be separated by 500 feet, 
so overall if you are approaching a workzone you should see the first warning sign as you are 2500 feet away from it, then another one at 2000 , 
and another one at 1500 etc...

So overall all those entities exist as objects:

1. Street object Begins and Ends at nodes, another property of streets is how long they are 5000 .
2. Work Zone Spans they have a begin and end property , where they mark the exact footage they begin and end at 
   (Example: workzone span starts at footage 500 in street 1 , and ends at street 9 at footage 3600.
3. Node objects , nodes have connection objects , connection objects tie two streets together
4. Connection objects that are part of the node and tell you which two streets tie to each other
5. warning sign objects, that i create at certain footages

So overall my approach was traverse through the streets,and check how far am I from a workzone begin/end. 
So I first check the street I am on, if there is no workzones begin/end on it, then I check the connections , 
to find out if there is a workzone begin/end there. If a workzone begin/end exists on the connecting street, 
then I determine how far is it. so if the connecting street is 2000 feet long , and the workzone begins at 1000, 
that means that I need to put three warning signs on the street that I am currently inspecting. 
But as you can see it could get quite complicated with the different possibilites. 
Given the fact that I am only able to handle one street at a time here is the part-solution I came up with but it's still incomplete as am not sure how to determine what is the maximum amount of warning signs necessary. The scenario attached bellow illustrates this, but basically how would i handle a situation where I have a work zone connection on two streets, that connect to a third street. How can I return the highest amount of signs required?
case:

// this method gets called to scan the street network from the left side to see if there are any workzones
// initially we pass offset as zero , and the given street

```
public static Double getLimitIncreasing(StreetVO street, Double offset) {
List<ConnectionVO> connections = street.getBeginNode().getConnections();
        for ( ConnectionVO connect : connections ) {
            StreetVO connectingStreet = connect.getOtherStreet(street);
            if ( connectingStreet.getSpans().containsKey(Constants.WORK_ZONE) ) {
                List<Double> connectionOffsets = getConnectionPoints(connectingStreet); // gets the points in footage where a workzone begins or ends on a given street, there could be multiple ones, and they are sorted in ascending
                Double streetLength = connectingStreet.getStreetLength();
                Double temp = 0.0;
                if ( connectionOffsets.isEmpty() && (streetLength + offset) < 2500 ) { // if we don't find any connections but the street is too small we have to look at the connecting
                // streets
                    temp = getLimitIncreasing(connectingStreet, (streetLength + offset), subdivision, logger, ptcDataModel); // look at the next connections 
                    if ( temp < offset ) {
                        offset = temp;
                    }
                } else if ( connectionOffsets.isEmpty() && (streetLength + offset) > 2500 ) {
                    continue;
                } else if ( connectionOffsets.size() >= 1 ) {
                    offset = offset + (streetLength - connectionOffsets.get(connectionOffsets.size() - 1)); // gets the last connection, and subtract it from the length to get how far from the end of the street are we
                }
            }
        }
        if ( offset != 0 ) {
            return offset;
        } else {
            return -1.0;
        }
    }

    public class StreetVO{

        NodeVO beginNode
        NodeVO endNode
        Double streetLength;
        Map<String,Span> spans // There are other kinds of spans , that exist , workzones-dangerzones, etc... for this part of the problem i am only concerned about workzones, so passing the key value of workzone, will return to me a span object that lets me know whether a work zone on this current street exists , and whether it begins/ends on a different street along with the exact offset it begins/ends at.
        }
    public class NodeVO(){ //
        List<ConnectionVO> connections;

    }
    public class Span(){ // a workzone can exist on two different street or the same street, and it should have a begin offset , and an end offset
        Double beginOffset;
        StreetVO workZoneBeginStreet;
        StreetVO workZoneEndStreet;
        Double endOffset;

    }
    public class ConnectionVO(){ // this object tells you which two streets connect to each other
        StreetVO beginStreet;
        StreetVO endStreet;
        public getOtherStreet(StreetVO street){ // given one street it will return the other one it's connected to
        if(street == beginStreet)return endStreet else return beginStreet

        }

    }
```

[Example Scenario Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot817.png)

Attached above is an example scenario to help in visualizing the problem and the desired solution. But as you can see it can get quite tedious in figuring out the navigation paths. Is recursion the best approach?

Comment: "But does not work properly". Can you elaborate on what it does/does not do correctly? Any specific place in the code you think may be the source?

Comment: As far as I understood your task, it's basically distance-limited graph traversal. Check [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/), I've found it very useful for different graph tasks.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking interest in this. It does not work properly because I am not sure how to recursively setup a base case where I can ensure that at the end I get the shortest connection path. I need to retrieve the shortest connection , because I need to ensure that I place the maximum amount of signs necessary on a certain traversable path.

Comment: Just some hints--not an answer: You don't define Span, it's important because I can't figure out how you determine where on a StreetVO a span starts and ends.  Also a couple hints:  I'd let Node and Connection help you out more by moving code into them (and out of your big function).  For instance I think your two if statements might be replaced with a single "getConnectedWorkZones" method on one of those classes.  Recursion is probably the best approach, but you will probably need a list of "Visited" nodes to ensure you don't recurse the same path more than once.